# Get installed version of package in Puppet when latest is specified

Tags: jenkins, puppet

When a package in puppet is set to `latest`, how can the installed version be retrieved?

In the following example, `jenkins` package is set to download the latest available in repo. But after download, I'd like to get the actual installed version.

```
package { 'jenkins':
  ensure => latest,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have a custom fact. Depending on your OS, you could do something like this for a RedHat machine:

```
Facter.add("jenkins_version") do
  confine :osfamily => 'RedHat'
  setcode do
    Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("/bin/rpm -q jenkins")
  end
end
```

Then you'll have a `$::jenkins_version` fact, which you can output with `notify{$::jenkins_version:}`

Comment: Keep in mind that facts are set at the start of a run, so if jenkins is updated in a run, this will tell you the version that was installed before the update.

Comment: Right, I was thinking along this restriction. It seems like the version of the installed package has to be returned (or notified) immediately after. In my case, I need the installed package version to populate a config file so using facter doesn't address my need.

Comment: Puppet is not really fit to provide for this scenario. You'll have to bend in one of two uncomfortable directions. 1) Your fact represents the **available** version of `jenkins`, and your manifest is faithful that the update will indeed work. 2) You don't use a fact after all, and make Puppet populates said config file with a script on the agent side, using an `exec` resource, that reads the version at runtime. As I said, both options have rather severe drawbacks.